# How to add meta tags to Liferay page

Tags: facebook, liferay, liferay-6, meta-tags

For a Facebook share button, I deed to add some meta tags to a page in Liferay.
The result of the HTML should look like the following example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="My website title" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="4711" />
  </head>
  <body>...</body>
</html>
```

How can I do that in Liferay WITHOUT coding but just by configuration in the admin control area?

Note: For www.mydomain.com/en the content of the meta tag should be in English. For www.mydomain.com/de it should be in German.
If this is not possible by configuration easily, it can be all in one single language.

Comment: 1)https://github.com/juliocamarero/facebook-liferay-integration/downloads
2)https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12275755
This links might help you

Comment: Meta-tags can be added in the theme

Comment: Thank you. I hope it is possible to add meta tags without installing additional integration plugins. However, I could not find a way to edit our theme. Is it possible that we don't use any theme? How could I add meta tags in that case?

Comment: There are some meta tags available in the site pages configuration - however, it's a finite set of meta tags out-of-the-box. If your portal looks like Liferay, you might not have any theme. If it has your organization's look&feel, you'll have one (typically everyone has one). If you don't have one, the standard one is easily customized - and then you can access portal_normal.vm as given in the one answer that's already there while I write this comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can add fb meta tags in portal_normal.vm in theme.
Also,these changes are not instantly reflected but takes a while until the fb crawlers re cache content from your tags.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Adding the tags to portal_normal.vm solves the problem. However, only in one single language. Is there a way to have one version per language?

Comment: I found out, that I can add a locale if-else switch:

Comment: I found out, that I can add a locale if-else switch in  portal_normal.vm: #if ($themeDisplay.getLocale() == "de_DE") ... <meta property="og:title" content="German title" /> ... #else ... <meta property="og:title" content="English title" /> ... #end ... However, Facebook always uses English when crawling. So, the user gets the correct meta tag content in the localized HTML page, but Facebook always shows the English text in the FB like box. How can I achieve that the Facebook crawler processes both languages correctly?

Comment: Have not come across such a case myself..will check up though!

Comment: You can use the following and try                                  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
    <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />

Comment: Very interesting. However, adding the required logic to implement that approach via portal_normal.vm in Liferay seems a bit complicated to just implement a simple share button. I hope there is a smarter way to implement a FB share button with Liferay including i18n support.

Comment: See meta tags are a must for appropriate title,text and image.Just that the locale support need to be looked into.Though,in liferay you have social integration available for all assets,which can be used likewise for other components

Comment: Thanks. What do you exactly mean by "you have social integration available"? Do you mean installing plugins like https://github.com/juliocamarero/facebook-liferay-integration/downloads ? Is there a way to configure the meta tags without additional installations/plugins?

Comment: Hopefully you must have figured out some solution by now.Still to clarify,by the above comment,I refer to plugins integrated for social integration.But,to the best of my knowledge,there is nothing per se to directly integrate meta tags:)